# Appcelerator Titanium: Android SDK doesn't load

Tags: iphone, android, titanium, appcelerator

I started developing with Titanium and now I really stuck on one part.
I downloaded the Adroid SDK and added the path to Titanium:

/Users/michael/Downloads/android-sdk-mac_86/

I can open e.g. Kitchen Sink in the iPhone Simulator without problems, but when I want to open it in Android then my screen looks like this: [Screenshot](http://img526.imageshack.us/i/bildschirmfoto20100330u.png/)

Why is down there all the time, even after 2 hours of waiting, the label "loading..." ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to open your Android_SDK_Dir/tools, run file android to create a new Android Virtual Device. After that, open your Titanium again. Maybe this will solve your issue.

Take a look at your image. Value of SDK listbox is "...loading...". This means you Titanium cannot determine which Android Virtual Device is. So, as I said, try to create new Android Virtual Device first.

Answer (score 2):

some great advice given here - helped me out.

Switching to TRACE will probably show that Android SDK Platform 1.6 and API 4 is missing.

[More info here](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/25681/project-creation-error-error-creating-project-please-try-again)

Answer (score 2):

1) You can install Android SDK 1.6 (run tools/android from your Android SDK folder and download the older SDK 1.6 from the Google Repository),
and Titanium will detect Android SDK

2) As for Android SDK 2.2, adb moved to platform-tools folder, so you will have to create a link in [your-android-sdk-folder]/tools e.g. :
ln -s ../platform-tools/adb

(full instructions for non-linux here : http://guides.appcelerator.com/en/getting_started.html)

Finally, in the Titanium Test&Package/Run emulator window, you will have the choice between Android SDK 1.6 and 2.2

Answer (score 0):

having the same issue - have you found a workaround?
found out that after downloading the android sdk - there are other components to be downloaded, which is different from previous versions. Also found some implication that loading the android emulator prior to launching the app from titanium may yield better results.

check the android docs for updating the sdk via the avd manager

load the emulator first video:
http://vimeo.com/10866226

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the Filter from "Info" to "Trace" that may illuminate things.

Most commonly, you may not have the right platforms installed.  Just install all of them if that's the case.

Answer (score 0):

add a blank folder android-7 in android/platforms ..n restart titanium ..it worked for me on ubuntu